# Change complex str to float in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset which contains column with data about seniority in company of the form: `'9 years 9 months 14 days'` in `str` format. I transformed them to `float` by `for` cycle with regular expression:

```
for row in range(len(df)):
    target = df['seniority'][row]
    content = re.findall(r'\d+', target)
    content[0] = float(content[0])
    content[1] = (float(content[1]))/12
    content[2] = ((float(content[2]))/30)/12
    content = sum(content)
    df['seniority'][row] = content
```

It works.
But I interested in more effective and fast way to do that if it exist.

Comment: Is this always the format? And you want the final float in years?

Comment: Yes and yes. Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Setup***:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'sen': ['9 years 9 months 14 days', '2 years 4 months 12 days']
})
```

***Option 1***:
List comprehension with **`str.findall`**

```
df['seniority'] = [
    sum((float(x), float(y)/12, float(z)/365))
    for x, y, z in df.sen.str.findall(r'(\d+)').values
]

# Result

                        sen  seniority
0  9 years 9 months 14 days   9.788356
1  2 years 4 months 12 days   2.366210
```

***Option 2***:
**`str.extract`** with **`div`** and **`sum`**:

```
df.sen.str.extract(r'.*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)').astype(float).div([1, 12, 365]).sum(1)

0    9.788356
1    2.366210
dtype: float64
```

***Timings***:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

%%timeit                                                  
for row in range(len(df)):                                
    target = df['sen'][row]                               
    content = re.findall(r'\d+', target)                  
    content[0] = float(content[0])                        
    content[1] = (float(content[1]))/12                   
    content[2] = ((float(content[2]))/30)/12              
    content = sum(content)
242 ms ± 1.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit                                                  
df['seniority'] = [                                   
    sum((float(x), float(y)/12, float(z)/365))        
    for x, y, z in df.sen.str.findall(r'(\d+)').values
]
29.9 ms ± 136 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.sen.str.extract(r'.*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)').astype(float).div([1,12, 365]).sum(1)
29 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```